# Pass char pointer to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am trying to get Mac address by this code:

```
void getMacAdress(unsigned char **address)
{
    int s;
    struct ifreq buffer;

    s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    memset(&buffer, 0x00, sizeof(buffer));
    strcpy(buffer.ifr_name, "eth0");
    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &buffer);
    close(s);
    *address = (unsigned char *)buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data;

    for (s = 0; s < 6; s++)
    {
        printf("%.2X ", *(*address + s));
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char *address;

    getMacAdress(&address);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%.2X ", *(address + i));
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I got a correct result as

```
08 00 27 0A 4E 98 
08 00 27 0A 4E 98
```

but when I delete `printf` snippet code in `getMacAddress()` function it becomes:

```
void getMacAdress(unsigned char **address)
{
    int s;
    struct ifreq buffer;

    s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    memset(&buffer, 0x00, sizeof(buffer));
    strcpy(buffer.ifr_name, "eth0");
    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &buffer);
    close(s);
    *address = (unsigned char *)buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data;
    printf("\n");
}
```

I got the wrong result

```
08 00 00 00 00 00
```

Can you explain to me why that is and how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you passing a "pointer to pointer to char"?

Comment: I think the pointer you write into your var gets invalidated as soon as you exit the function, since your buffer is on the stack.

Comment: You copy a pointer to a local variable in `getMacAdress()` into the `address` passed into it from `main()`, and that leads to undefined behaviour.  The space is reused and you get what you get (and you're lucky you didn't crash).

Comment: malloc some memory to `*address` and `strcpy (*address , buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot point to a stack space to return in a function.

Instead, you can malloc a heap space to store the result you wanted:

```
void getMacAdress(unsigned char **address)
{
    int s;
    struct ifreq buffer;

    s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    memset(&buffer, 0x00, sizeof(buffer));
    strcpy(buffer.ifr_name, "eth0");
    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &buffer);
    close(s);
    *address = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data));
    memcpy(*address, buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data,sizeof(buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data));

    //for (s = 0; s < 6; s++)
    //{
    //    printf("%.2X ", *(*address + s));
    //}

    //printf("\n");
}
```

BTW, don't forget to free the heap space in your main function.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is here:

```
*address = (unsigned char *)buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data;
```

`buffer` is a local variable to your function. So the pointer you are storing in `address` points to a local variable which is destroyed when the function returns, leaving a dangling pointer.

Trying to read from this pointer causes undefined behaviour. Your output can be explained depending on whether the memory was re-used for something else already by the time you did the print or not.

Comment: Yes, i understand but why the adding printf function in getMacAdress() leads to getting a true result?

Comment: @Sam Deferencing an out-of-scope local pointer is undefined behavior, meaning anything could happen. Calling printf just happens to trigger some behind-the-scenes quackery that changed the nature of the undefined behavior.

Comment: It's just luck.  By chance, the old data was not overwritten by stack pushes.  Your memory pointed to by `address` was kind of in limbo.  It was set up to be freed but nothing overwrote it yet because not much else used the stack.

Comment: @Sam yeah, it helps to think of it like you're building an apartment with a bunch of stories, and on the 2nd floor someone wrote a book and left the only copy there. When the `getMacAddress` function exists the 2nd floor is marked condemned, but everything stays put until you call additional functions in `main`. What happens when you get lucky is that that `printf` in `main` happens upon that book and prints it, even though other things on that floor might have been replaced with walls or in this case space for `int i` and the associated calls to `printf`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fix it...

```
//*address = (unsigned char *)buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data;
*address = malloc (strlen (buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data) + 1);
strcpy (*address, buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data);
```